# Scale NSString Font to UIImage Size

Tags: xcode, nsstring, uiimage, font-size, autoresize

I'm writing text onto a image taken from the iDevice's camera or chosen from the photo library but I need the fontsize scaled according to width/height of the image. Here's my current code: 
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);

```
CGRect aRectangle = CGRectMake(0,0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
[img drawInRect:aRectangle];

[[UIColor whiteColor] set];           // set text color
NSInteger fontSize = 45;
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];// set text font

[ text drawInRect : aRectangle                      // render the text
         withFont : font
    lineBreakMode : UILineBreakModeTailTruncation  // clip overflow from end of last line
        alignment : UITextAlignmentCenter ];

UIImage *theImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();   // extract the image
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();     // clean  up the context.
return theImage;</i>
```

Comment: Do you want the text to be a single line or multiple lines?

Comment: Join the fontScaling chat room.

Comment: @Kent I'm getting this message: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.
I'm still a new member.

Comment: Ah.  Bummer.  So more questions.  Do you want the text to be the full height of the image or is there some other limit?

Comment: @Kent Well for this part of the text I want it to be just like a center title of the image. Like for a image with the dimensions 960x750 I'd have the font size set to 45 so it's right in the middle and big enough to be seen, but the problem is I can't have the font size always be 45 since images' sizes vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this.  It creates a rect half the size of your image, then uses a binary search to zoom in on the font size you want.

```
//---- initial data
CGSize szMax = CGSizeMake(<imgWidth> / 2, <imgHeight> / 2);
CGFloat fMin = 2;      //-- the smallest size font we want
CGFloat fMax = 100;    //-- the largest size font we want
CGFloat fMid;          //-- the middle of min and max

while ((fMax - fMin) >= 1.0)    //-- repeat until the sizes converge
{
    fMid = (fMin + fMax) / 2.0;    //-- compute mid-point

    UIFont *pfnt = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: fMid];    //-- create middle-sized font

    //---- compute the size of the text using the mid-sized font
    CGSize szStr = [pStr sizeWithFont: pfnt constrainedToSize: szMax lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    if (szStr.height > szMax.height)
        fMax = fMid;                //-- text too tall, set max to mid-point
    else               
        fMin = fMid;                //-- text too short, set min to mid-point
}
//---- 'fMid' is the size you want.
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement the code but I'm a little confused how it works, could you possibly explain it? I'm very new to Objective C, I've been programing in .NET and C# for the past 7+ years so the adjustment is a little complicating.

Comment: One question question @Kent, I'm not sure what to set my UIFont to, I tried fMid and fMin but the text is over the entire image.

Comment: See last comment.  At the end of the loop, fMid should be the size you want.  Add NSLog statements to see the values of fMin, fMax, and szStr at each loop.  Are you in Atl?

Comment: Wow thanks! That helped a lot. :) 
I am having a few problems, I set <imgWidth> and <imgHeight> to img.size.width and img.size.height, could that cause the text to cover the entire image? Also I'm not sure what pStr and szMaxWidth is. I replaced pStr with my NSString but I'm not sure if that fixed much.

Comment: Are you in Atl?  Note that my code sets szMax to `<imgHeight> / 2`.  pStr is your string.

Comment: That fixed those problems, I'm just unsure about szMaxWidth now. Do I need to change that to szMax? I'm not familiar with Atl..